# ipywidgets Text on_change is buggy refreshes while typing

Tags: python, onchange, observers, ipywidgets

I am using ipywidgets.Text and written a function that would run when the text has changed. that function is time-intensive. The Text takes integers up to 1000.

```
from ipywidgets import Text
a = Text(description = "Type here", placeholder = "integer: ex: 123")

def on_change(change):
    if change["new"]!= change["old"]:
        print(change)
        #some time intensive code
a.observe(on_change, names =["value"])
```

so, when I type say 123, the on_change function runs for 1,12 and 123(picture attached).
[image]
Can I somehow eliminate it running for 1 and 12?

One obvious idea is to keep an explicit button and run only when that is clicked..
but isn't there a better idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `continuous_update=False` to your widget.

```py
a = Text(
    description = "Type here", 
    placeholder = "integer: ex: 123",
    continuous_update=False
)
```

Using this parameter your on_change function will receive the value only when the user: press enter or remove the focus from the input.